# if($_POST) and if (isset($_POST['save'])) on same button?

Tags: php, post

so problem... two php files... first file is php and input form and second is connect do database...  problem is when i change button input name... when put "save" got insert to database if change to "submit" then validation work but not inserting to data base... i was try to change in connect `if(isset($_POST['save']))` save to confirm still nothing in databse...

this is first file with validation field and input field

```
<?php
 if($_POST)
{
    $errors = array();
    //start validation
    if(empty($_POST['naziv_objekta']))
    {
        $errors['naziv_objekta1'] = "Field cannot be empty";
    }

    //check errors
    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {

header('Location: http://blablabla/connect_test.php/');

exit();

    }
}

?>

<form action="connect_test.php" method="post"/>
<table width="545" border="0" align="center" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="257">Naziv objekta:</td>
                <td width="278"> <input type="text" placeholder="Unesite naziv objekta" name="naziv_objekta" id="naziv_objekta" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['naziv_objekta'])) echo $_POST['naziv_objekta']; ?>" /><p><?php if(isset($errors['naziv_objekta1'])) echo $errors['naziv_objekta1']; ?></p>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <th align="center" valign="middle"><input onclick="return confirm('Da li ste sigurni?');" align="middle" type="Submit" name="save"  value="sacuvaj"/></th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

second file (part of connect file). part becaus its very big.

```
<?php

$host   = "localhost";

$user   = "blablabla";

$pass   = "blablabla";

$db = "blablabla";

$link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

if (!$link) {

die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

}

if(isset($_POST['save']))

$values1 = $_POST['naziv_objekta'];

$values2 = $_POST['maticni_broj'];
```

Comment: Show your whole form. The button is named `submit`, not `save`.

Comment: i said i was try combination it means with changing "name"

Comment: @Barmar is ok now?

Comment: Why do you redirect when there are no errors in validation? The redirect doesn't post the form data.

Comment: do you mean "header('Location: http://blablabla/connect_test.php/');" its just one of combination... if i delete it i got blank page "blablala\/unos_korisnika_probni.php/connect_test.php"

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. That redirects and then ends the script, so you never process the form data.

Comment: If you delete that, `exit()` still ends the script. When the input is valid, you need to go directly to the part of the script that updates the database.

Comment: yeah.. i started without that but whn is inserting correctly then working fine... when try to not fill that field and click to save then i got Field cannot be empty.. but when i fill it page stop working correctly... somehow remember data it that fild and wont insert and again got  "blablala\/unos_korisnika_probni.php/connect_test.php"

Answer (score 0):

The code that performs the database update should be in the `if (count($errors) == 0)` block.

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $host   = "localhost";
    $user   = "blablabla";
    $pass   = "blablabla";
    $db = "blablabla";
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    if (!$link) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $values1 = $_POST['naziv_objekta'];
        $values2 = $_POST['maticni_broj'];
        ...
    }
}
```

You were also mssing the `{` after `if (isset($_POST['save']))`, so it wasn't grouping all the statements into that block.

Comment: i was try but same again... and now if put only to validation field it is insertet to data base... if fill more then get connet_test.php sh*t... i think i will delete all and kill myself...